# laravel join two tables based array of id's

Tags: laravel

I have two tables **purchases** & **purchase_types**. In the purchases table one field is "`purchaseCategories`" where the data is stored as an array of id's(from `purchase_types`) like `[1,2]`.

the `purchase_types` table look like this--

| id | purchaseType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Purchase Type 1 |
| 2 | Purchase Type 2 |
| 3 | Purchase Type 3 |

and the `purchases` table look like this--

| id | purchaseCategory |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `[1,2]` |
| 2 | `[1,2,3]` |
| 3 | `[1,3]` |

I have tried this--

```
$purchaseIds = [1, 2];

        $purchases = DB::table('purchases')
            ->join('purchase_types', 'purchases.purchaseCategory', '=', 'purchase_types.id')
            ->whereIn('purchases.purchaseCategory', $purchaseIds)
            ->get();

        dd($purchases);
```

This shows empty array.

how do I join this two tables to show the purchase types in my blade file?

Comment: You can load the relation using  `->with('purchaseType')` and then access it like : `$category->purchaseType->id`

Comment: I think the problem is that the structure of your purchases table is incompatible with how JOIN works.  It seems like you want the join condition to operate on each array element in a purchaseCategory, but JOIN doesn't work that way (AFAIK).  Without knowing what DB you're using, I'll guess that purchaseCategory is a string type column, so your join conditional will never be satisfied

Comment: @imabug then how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal, but you could use `JSON_CONTAINS` as your join condition. Your `whereIn` should also be `JSON_CONTAINS`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    purchases AS p
INNER JOIN
    purchase_types AS pt
    ON JSON_CONTAINS(p.purchaseCategory, CAST(pt.id AS CHAR(50)))
WHERE
    JSON_CONTAINS(p.purchaseCategory, "[1,2]")
```

The casting is necessary because JSON_CONTAINS expects a string. Passing the  pt.id column directly would cause an error.

```php
$purchaseIds = [1, 2];
$purchases = DB::table('purchases', 'p')
    ->join('purchase_types AS pt', function ($join) {
        $join->whereJsonContains('p.purchaseCategory', DB::raw('CAST(pt.id AS CHAR(50))'));
    })
    ->whereJsonContains('p.purchaseCategory', $purchaseIds)
    ->get();
```

Here's a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3rEfr1xjEPGubYpMVExAu4/5) demonstrating this query.

Comment: Thanks. But when I add another input in $purchaseIds = [1,2,3] it returns an empty array. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Weird. Testing it on DB fiddle, it worked.